# Is it worth developing a CPU intensive mobile app?

Tags: performance, mobile, user-experience

I am considering developing a poker robot to play against for mobile phones.
Needless to say that this is a very CPU intensive application as confirmed by the prototype.

What is the consensus on a CPU intensive mobile apps? Is it even worth developing? My concern is that people will leave negative feedback similar to "CPU Hog. Uninstall".

I could host the CPU intensive brain on a server, but that requires an internet connection for the user, which is undesirable.

Comment: Why is this CPU intensive and why is that needless to say? Keeping track of 52 cards should not require much by way of memory or processing power. Do you use complex strategy models? Could they be simplified?

Comment: Keeping track of cards is not the issue. The math is quite intense there to evaluate the board, hence the high CPU usage. This could be simplified at the expense of precision and therefore the poker robot strength.

Answer (score 0):

It's not worth it if you're dropping frames, especially on mobile. Mobile is very limited comparatively speaking to PC or console, so you have to plan accordingly.

I'd attempt at trying to add as much pre-processed tasks that as possible can be accessed later on without further processing, thus only needing to call the pre-processed data. This'll definitely save quite a bit of CPU usage.

If you can't do it, then it's not worth it unless you can keep the game within a small margin of error which won't be noticed by the average person within your audience.

Comment: The graphics is not intense in this one. The robot already pre-loads many tables with pre-calculated and hard coded values. There is, of course, room for improvement. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I see, well, sorry I can't further answer your question.